# NMinimize for searching global minimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have been trying to find global minimum for this equation for some time now.

The equation is quite easy to understand. It is made with sumation of stress equations of points on the border where $σ_{rr,i} = σ_{r\varphi,i} = 0$, where $i$ stand for $i$-th hole of $n$ holes. So I have multiple points with those two equations and I sum them in equation below:

$eq=σ_{rr,i}^2 + σ_{r\varphi,i}^2+σ_{rr,i+1}^2 + σ_{r\varphi,i+1}^2 +...$

Each of the functions has coefficients $A_{1}, B_{1}, C_{1}, D_{1}, A_{2} ... $ Then I use Simplify on $eq$ and get something like:

$K_1 A_1 + K_2 B_1 ...$ where $K_j$ is real number and value of $A, B, C, D$ is what I am looking for. Below is a picture of this equation.

[image]

Now I use the function as follows:

$NMinimize[eq, kList]$ where $kList=[A_1, B_1 ...]$.

The lowest result that I get is around 40 000, and values are not correct. I know there is a solution and if I plot the function I can tell if results are correct.

Everything works with only one set of points, with two sets of points NMinimize doesnt find the minimum. There are 14 coefficients in the $kList$.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
pointsFlat = ToPolarCoordinates@Flatten[points, 1];
eqList = Simplify@
   Flatten@Table[{Subscript[\[Sigma], rr][N@pointsFlat[[i, 1]], 
       N@pointsFlat[[i, 2]]], 
      Subscript[\[Sigma], r\[CurlyPhi]][N@pointsFlat[[i, 1]], 
       N@pointsFlat[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length@pointsFlat}];
```

KList:

```
{Subscript[A, 1, 0], Subscript[A, 1, 1], Subscript[B, 1, 1], \
Subscript[A, 1, 2], Subscript[B, 1, 2], Subscript[C, 1, 2], \
Subscript[D, 1, 2], Subscript[A, 2, 0], Subscript[A, 2, 1], \
Subscript[B, 2, 1], Subscript[A, 2, 2], Subscript[B, 2, 2], \
Subscript[C, 2, 2], Subscript[D, 2, 2]}
```

Searching for solution:

```
NMinimize[Total[eqList^2], kList, MaxIterations -> 10000,Method -> 
"DifferentialEvolution"
```

And the output is:

```
{40704.3, {Subscript[A, 1, 0] -> -57.9097, 
Subscript[A, 1, 1] -> 1.2073, Subscript[B, 1, 1] -> 0.00694863, 
Subscript[A, 1, 2] -> -34.5356, Subscript[B, 1, 2] -> 0.0454918, 
Subscript[C, 1, 2] -> 69.305, Subscript[D, 1, 2] -> -0.0722133, 
Subscript[A, 2, 0] -> -2.56125, Subscript[A, 2, 1] -> 1.06113, 
Subscript[B, 2, 1] -> 0.280895, Subscript[A, 2, 2] -> 2.14184, 
Subscript[B, 2, 2] -> -0.155145, Subscript[C, 2, 2] -> -5.80381, 
Subscript[D, 2, 2] -> -0.0825128}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Does `{a10->-58.7044,a11->1.62465,a12->-35.0203,a20->-5.59812,a21->1.68903,a22->3.58614,b11->0.0173066,b12->0.0400712,b21->0.258563,b22->-0.109889,c12->70.2487,c22->-9.30985,d12->-0.0471049,d22->-0.126398}` give you a result less than 100000

Comment: Hey, it gives me result of 40 000. I added some new information above. But the results are not correct. When I plot function with those coefficients I can see that they are not correct.

Comment: The execution of `pointsFlat = ToPolarCoordinates@Flatten[points, 1];
     eqList = Simplify@Flatten@Table[{Subscript[\[Sigma], rr] 
           [N@pointsFlat[[i, 1]], N@pointsFlat[[i, 2]]], 
          Subscript[\[Sigma], 
           r\CurlyPhi]][N@pointsFlat[[i, 1]], 
    N@pointsFlat[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, 
   Length@pointsFlat}];` produces an error.

Comment: Hey, im kinda new, there was some bracket error in code, I edited post and here is also the working one. `pointsFlat = ToPolarCoordinates@Flatten[points, 1];
eqList = Simplify@
   Flatten@Table[{Subscript[\[Sigma], rr][N@pointsFlat[[i, 1]], 
       N@pointsFlat[[i, 2]]], 
      Subscript[\[Sigma], r\[CurlyPhi]][N@pointsFlat[[i, 1]], 
       N@pointsFlat[[i, 2]]]}, {i, 1, Length@pointsFlat}];`

Comment: Sorry, still an error "ToPolarCoordinates::rectt: Rectangular array expected at position 1 in ToPolarCoordinates[Flatten[points,1]].".

Comment: Well you dont have an array of points and also the functions. The code you are trying to run makes the equation on the picture above.